# Calabash-iOS and Xcode

Tags: ios, calabash

I am trying to use Calabash-iOS for test automation.But I am not aware of the relevance of Xcode in Calabash. I downloaded Xcode 4.6.3, Ruby 1.9.3 , cucumber to start off. I am stuck with how to use Xcode for automation. I have the ipa file of the application to be tested.
When I browsed, steps are given to put the calabash-framework into the app that you are going to test.Why this should be done? And what is the specific use with Xcode tool ?I am going to test with an iPhone  so why is xcode needed. kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

> The Calabash framework uses private Apple APIs to synthesize touch
>   events.

That's why you need to include `calabash.framework` into .app bundle before being able to run your scenarios against the application. The .ipa without the framework built into it won't be able to accept calls and react according to your scenarios.

You need source code of the iOS application and Xcode to integrate `calabash.framework` into, and build new .app bundle. Separate build target with `-cal` suffix being created as per the [setting-up-xcode-project](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#setting-up-xcode-project) instructions (note the `-force_load "$(SRCROOT)/calabash.framework/calabash" -lstdc++` instruction, which influences how the bundle is going to be organized).

Hence, you won't be able to take an .ipa file, which is generally deployed to the store, and run your calabash scenarios against it (unless .ipa was mistakenly or intentionally built with the framework included). You can check your .ipa weather it includes the framework or not: [instructions here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#important-notice).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 7 Xcode is required because calabash needs to launch the app with Instruments (which is included in the Xcode.app bundle).

Answer (score 0):

The linking between calabash.framework and your project it's just to start the Calabash iOS server when your app is launched.
So when you code and run your tests in whatever framework you will use to do that, this procedure will do the magic communicating the calabash and your tests.

Reference: [Tutorial: Link Calabash in Debug config](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Link-Calabash-in-Debug-config)